# Retrieving a collection from a generic method with a run time generic type

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

I have a generic method

```
var propertyResolverMethod = _propertyResolver
    .GetType()
    .GetMethod(
        nameof(_propertyResolver.GetEntities),
        new[] { typeof(string), typeof(string) })
    ?.MakeGenericMethod(_itemType);
```

and  the invocation

```
var recommendedItems = propertyResolverMethod
    ?.Invoke(
        _propertyResolver,
        new object[] { itemId, ResolvedCollectionId });
```

It on the compile-time it returns an object, but on runtime, it returns `IQueryable<Item>` this item is the item from _itemType and we find out its type only on runtime, but I know that it has a collection inside Item.RelatedItems that I need to get. Tried already casting to dynamic, but does not work for my case, I know that's somehow solvable via Expressions.

Should be iteratable like this

```
var itemIds = recommendedItems?.Select(i => i.RelatedItems.Select(s => s.ItemID));
```

But it's not possible without a proper cast

Answer (score 0):

Hmm..

So if I get you correctly, you know this method returns an `IQueryable<Item>` where `Item`  is the type previously stored in `_itemType` and you also know for a fact that this type always defines `RelatedItems` which in turn are an `IEnumerable<T>` or `IQueryable<T>` with `T`defining `ItemID`?

Is there a type that all possible `_itemTypes` inherit from that has `RelatedItems` defined? If so, you could try casting to that...

Else you could do more Reflection magic:
If you know that your result is an `IQueryable<TItem>`, you can extract the property-getter for `RelatedItems` with Reflection and pass *that* to the Select-function (which you can get by eithre casting to `IQueryable<object>` or by using ... again ... Reflection.

But to be honest that would be a very, very dirty way to do it and I would only do it as a last resort.

My first instinct right now would be to try refactoring the containing class (`_itemType` hints to me that this is a member field), so it is generic as well (inheriting from a non-generic class if you need that), so the class *knows* the type through its own type parameter.

Another solution would be to have a function like this:

```
private <Type of itemIDs> GetRelatedItemIds<TItem>(object source) {
 return ((IQueriable<TItem>)source)?.Select(i => i.RelatedItems.Select(s => s.ItemID));
}
```

Now get that method via Reflection and use `MakeGenericMethod(_itemType)` on it, then invoke it with your result.

Just beware that your current selection will return a nested enumerable/queryable which each entry being a list of ItemIDs. If you didn't mean to do that, use `SelectMany` instead of the first `Select` which will automatically concatenate the inner enumerables/queryables.

I hope this helps you find a solution.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't change the _itemType

Comment: And also it's an IQueryable and we can't just simply extract a getter property. Should use an expression as I got